How can I use ByteBuffer with JDBI / Postgres for bytea columns?
In order to reduce memory allocations, I would like to use Java's ByteBuffer (or Netty's ByteBuf) in conjunction with JDBI. The datastore is Postgresql and I know how to get bytea columns in and out with byte[].
My application uses a lot of binary data and processes them internally as in Byte Buffers. Byte Buffers can be pooled and allocated off-heap but when reading or writing to the database there's always a byte[] array in between which reduces the efficiency Byte Buffers.
So is there a way to tell JDBIs object mappers to

write binary contents to a pre-allocated Byte Buffer
read binary contents from a Byte Buffer backed field of a POJO

